# Setting the properties of form values from another class

Tags: c#, forms

I have been working on an assignment with forms for a while now and everything works, however my professor want us to devide everything in seperate classes.

So what I have now is:

```
MainForm.cs
  MainForm.Designer.cs
  MainForm.resx
program.cs
```

In the MainForm.cs is where i have all my code and where i call the buttons, labels, textboxes etc from.
What I want to do, is to have a strucutre with other classes such as

```
MainForm.cs
  MainForm.Designer.cs
  MainForm.resx
program.cs
class1.cs
class2.cs
```

I tried doing this, but from my class1 i couldn't call the Design(name) of the Form since it dont exist in the context. I have been searching a lot but haven't found anything that matched my problem or how to solve it.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any property to be accessible from another class (another form for instance as `Form` itself is a class), the property must be public, so for example lets say you have a textbox named `txtSomething` and you need to access its text, you may create a public property that lets you get and set its `Text` property:

```
public string SomeProperty { get { return txtSomething.Text;} set {txtSomething.Text = value;}}
```

You can of course change `MainForm.Designer.cs` and make all controls (for example textboxes) public where they are defined, but it is not a good choice at all. because you should always give public access only where it is needed. for example if you need a controls text, let just its text property be accessible (the code above).

Even, if the second form has just to get the textbox value and does need to set it, you may give a readonly access. so the code above would be:

```
public string SomeProperty { get { return txtSomething.Text;} }
```

Then assuming that the instance of `FrmMain` is `frmMain` you can access the Text property of that textbox like:

```
string propertyValue = frmMain.SomeProperty;
```

Comment: Interesting, read a bit about it and figured out. Thanks for your reply!